# Saving image file and returning to whatsapp

Tags: android, image, drawing

I've used the following code to save an image file to the external storage

```
drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
String img = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),drawView.getDrawingCache(),UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpeg", "doodle");
```

I want to return this saved file to Whatsapp using an intent. Can somebody please help me out with the code? I'm new to android and would really appreciate it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: It says mBitmap has not been initialised. I initialised it to null but the application stops working.

Comment: can you post the error log . Also change the sdcard image location in the code given